# Estimating population correlation based on current data and a previous study

Tags: bayesian, correlation, meta-analysis

Assume:

- A previous study looking at the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ obtained a correlation of $r = 0.50$ using a sample of $n = 100$. The raw data is not available.
- The current study also looking at the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ obtained a correlation of $r = 0.45$ with $n = 50$.

How would you do the following tasks:

1. Give your best estimate of the population correlation between $X$ and $Y$ assuming the two studies are estimating the same correlation.
2. Give your best estimate of the population correlation between $X$ and $Y$ in the current study
   assuming that the first study is slightly different than the current study (e.g., it used a different measurement procedure, a different type of sample, etc.). Of course the weight given to the previous study would depend on perceived similarity with the second study. Thus, are there standard ways of quantifying similarity between studies in such calculations?

Answer (score 2):

The article on [Combinative Properties of Correlation Coefficients](http://www.jstor.org/stable/20150454) may have the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have easy access to the full-text, but from the opening page it does look useful regarding point 1 (i.e., combining two correlations).

Answer (score 1):

You can't hope to combine correlations with any legitimacy unless you also know the means and variances of the X's and Y's in each case, as well as their counts (*n*) and correlations (*r*).  The article Srikant Vadali refers to (Jack Dunlap, 1937) starts off by making exactly this assumption.  (It's easy to construct examples with the given values of your *n* and *r* statistics where the combined value of *r* is arbitrarily close to +1 or -1 or anything in between.)  Having these full second-moment statistics is crucial in the case of question (2) where one should expect there to be some systematic differences between the two studies.

Comment: Good point. However, in research settings this may or may not be possible. Means and standard deviations are typically known. However, in some cases a different measurement tool is used in the two studies. E.g., Imagine a study looking at the correlation between intelligence and job performance across jobs and two studies varied in the measurement of job performance or in the particular intelligence test used. Thus, the observed variables are on different metrics, even though the theorised latent variables are the same.

Comment: A necessary condition for combining these would be some quantitative relationship between the two forms of measurement, Jeromy.  Absent that, it's difficult to see how any combination of the two study results could be adequately defended.

Comment: The situation I mention above is standard practice in meta analytic studies of correlations. The "combining apples and oranges" critique is of course commonly raised regarding meta analysis. However, in defence of the practice, there is often substantial theoretical and empirical evidence that different measurements of the same construct (e.g., different intelligence measures) are highly correlated.

Comment: @Jeromy: Let's see whether I have understood. X and Y could be different measures of "intelligence." In study A, 100 people randomly drawn from a special school are tested. They all have comparable (low) levels of intelligence and r = 0.50. In study B, 50 gifted students are tested; they all have comparable (high) levels of intelligence and r = 0.45. If the raw data were to be combined, r would be almost 1.00. In study C, 50 more low-level people are studied and r = 0.45. The r from the combination of studies A and C would lie close to 0.45 or 0.50. How would a meta-analysis handle this?

Comment: typically X would be one variable (e.g., intelligence) and Y would be a different variable (e.g., average grade at university). Each study might use a slightly different measure of intelligence and a slightly different measure of average grade. Some meta analytic studies apply corrections for range restriction,  reliability of measurement, and other factors. Of course in the ideal situation the same measure would be used in all studies, and the raw data would be available, but meta analysis aims to synthesise results in the published literature as best as possible.